# Dont get deserialised json (jsonnet) to be viewed

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Im almost trying for 2 days with searching here and there to get the next organized.
This is my json-example (fetched with WebClient => DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler):

```
{"order_id":"12345678","itemList":["235724","203224","222224","222324","230021"],"amount":["65","50","10","25","42"]}
```

From json2sharp :

```
    public class RootObject
    {
        public string order_id { get; set; }
        public List<string> itemList { get; set; }
        public List<string> amount { get; set; }
    }
```

My Xaml:

```
  <ListBox x:Name="MyListBox" Height="344" Margin="0,107,0,245">
      <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
             <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="{Binding image}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding order_id}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding itemList}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding amount}"/>
             </StackPanel>
          </DataTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>
```

My cs:

```
 private void webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            return;
        }

        RootObject rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(e.Result);
        List<RootObject> myItems = rootObject.itemList.;
        foreach (var item in myItems)
        {
           MyListBox.Items.Add(item);  
        }

        Order_id.Text = rootObject.order_id.ToString();
        //MyListBox.ItemsSource = Root
        //MyListBox.DataContext = RootObject;
    }
```

Im able to show the string order_id to a , but i dont get listed the itemlist + amount.
Can someone put me in the right direction?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

**cs:**

```
        var result = "{'order_id':'12345678','itemList':['235724','203224','222224','222324','230021'],'amount':['65','50','10','25','42']}";
        var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(result);

        var items = new List<RootObject>
        {
            rootObject
        };

        MyListBox.ItemsSource = items;
```

**xaml:**

```
        <ListBox x:Name="MyListBox"
                 Margin="{StaticResource PhoneMargin}">

            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock.Inlines>
                                <Run Text="order_id:" />
                                <Run Text="{Binding order_id}" />
                            </TextBlock.Inlines>
                        </TextBlock>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="ItemList: " />
                            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding itemList}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="Amount: " />
                            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding amount}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

        </ListBox>
```

Comment: Thank you for this, finally i can go futher with this project.

Comment: @mmeulstee Can you mark my answer as answer of your question? Thanks

Comment: I tried and read alot but cant find a thing or dont understand to split that "public List<string> itemList { get; set; }" , the result must become a single string like "235724 X 65", also the "235742" is a part for a image url.