# How to manipulate the output to a ItemsSource?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

With this [Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21863096/dont-get-deserialised-json-jsonnet-to-be-viewed)
i was able too manage to show the output.
I've reading alot of posts here on stackoverflow, but cant find the right solution for the next:

How to manipulate the output too ItemsSource, because:

```
{"order_id":"12345678","itemList":["235724","203224","222224","222324","230021"],"amount":["65","50","10","25","42"]}
```

The number 235724 is also used within a IMG url and need to become like "235724 X 65" for a selectable listbox.

Solution was:

```
ObservableCollection<CreateItem> pitems = new ObservableCollection<CreateItem>();

        for (int i = 0; i < rootObject.itemList.Count; i++)
        {
            var itemsku = rootObject.itemList[i];
            var amount = rootObject.amount[i];
            pitems.Add(new CreateItem() { pTitle = itemsku + " X " + amount , pImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(string.Format("http://image.mgam79.nl/indb/{0}.jpg", itemsku)))});   
        }

        MyListBox.ItemsSource = pitems;

    public class CreateItem
    {
        public string pTitle { get; set; }
        public ImageSource pImage { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create in RootObject.cs a new property:

```
    public List<string> ImageUrls { get; set;}
```

---

In cs:

```
        var result = "{'order_id':'12345678','itemList':['235724','203224','222224','222324','230021'],'amount':['65','50','10','25','42']}";
        var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(result);

        var imageUrls = new List<string>();

        foreach (var item in rootObject.itemList)
        {
            foreach (var amount in rootObject.amount)
            {
                imageUrls.Add(item + " X " + amount);
            }
            break;
        }

        rootObject.ImageUrls = imageUrls;

        var items = new List<RootObject>
        {
            rootObject
        };

        MyListBox.ItemsSource = items;
    }
```

---

In xaml:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock.Inlines>
                                    <Run Text="order_id:" />
                                    <Run Text="{Binding order_id}" />
                                </TextBlock.Inlines>
                            </TextBlock>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="ItemList: " />
                                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding itemList}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="Amount: " />
                                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding amount}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="ImageUrls: " />
                                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ImageUrls}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Hi could you explain to me why the image isnt showing if i do "<Image Source="{Binding ImageUrls}" />" instead of your example above?

Comment: @mmeulstee You need to specify the index of ImageUrl. Try `"{Binding ImageUrls[0]}"`

Comment: Nice nver thought about that, so i need to create in xaml a list like about 30 of those lines since the list can be variable from 1 to many.

Comment: @mmeulstee No. The index will always be [0] because you create ItemTemplate for a single item in a collection.

Comment: Index of imageUrl of a single item is always [0]. :)

Comment: im feeling such a noob on this

Comment: @mmeulstee I'm glad to hear it.